# Pandas:How to apply a complex function to a column of a dataframe, with two other columns as the input of the function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| Worker | Schedule    | Overtime | Product |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 1      | some string | some int | ABC     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2      | some string | some int | DEF     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 3      | some string | some int | GHI     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

I have wrote a complex function that takes "Schedule", "Overtime", and "Product" as input, and return a newly edited "Schedule".

```
def edit_schedule(Schedule, Overtime, Product):
    *some calculation ...* 
   return Schedule_edited
```

I tested this function with just 1 row of data and it works.

```
Schedule = some string
Overtime = some int
Product = 'ABC'

print(edit_schedule(Schedule, Overtime, Product))
```

Now, how do I apply this function to the entire dataframe, so that I would have a new column called "Schedule_Edited" that return the newly edited Schedule that is a result of the function being applied to each row of the data?

```
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+
| Worker | Schedule    | Overtime | Product | Schedule_Edited |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+
| 1      | some string | some int | ABC     | some string     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+
| 2      | some string | some int | DEF     | some string     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+
| 3      | some string | some int | GHI     | some string     |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+
```

The actual dataframe has millions of rows, so any method that could make the calculation faster is really appreciated.

Much appreciation for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apply` on rows

```py
def edit_schedule(row):
    Schedule = row['Schedule']
    Overtime = row['Overtime']
    Product = row['Product']
    *some calculation ...*
    return Schedule_edited


df['Schedule_Edited'] = df.apply(edit_schedule, axis=1)
```